# How does Chrome detect the operating system

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu

Pretty simple: I need to know how does Google Chrome browser detect on which operating system is running? I am mostly interested about the GNU/Linux flavor(s) in particular, say, how does Chrome know that it is running on Ubuntu vs. Debian or CentOS?

Comment: I'm not sure about Chrome but the standard way is to check the special file `/etc/issue`

Comment: This is a good start, too: /etc/issue. I have to run a few tests over the weekend to find out if this is it. Thanks! You could post this as an answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can detect the GNU/Linux flavor from a website, if that's what you're asking. On the other hand, Google Chrome source code *probably*  makes use of the information stored in the `/etc/*-release` files present in your system.

For instance, you can parse the contents of `/etc/os-release` to get the flavor of linux you're using.

Sample of my `/etc/os-release` file:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Sample Python script to parse it:

```
fields = {}
with open('/etc/os-release', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split('=')
        fields[key] = value

print "You're running %s" % fields['ID']
```

Running it:

```
$ ./parse.py 
You're running ubuntu
```

Comment: I am not asking if one can detect the O/S from a website - but how Chrome does detect the O/S internally. But it's a good start with /etc/os-release.

Comment: Well, as you can see in the  [source code of Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/infra/luci/appengine/swarming/swarming_bot/os_utilities.py&q=os-release&sq=package:chromium&l=734&dr=C) they do the same thing as my code: they try to parse the os-release file :)

Comment: That's very cool, thanks, I have to run a few tests over the weekend to find out if this is it.

Answer (score 0):

Look ... this is very easy ... you just need to view some files in **/etc** (In linux)

I think that Google Browser firsly checking Windows derictory (if it exists) then it's opening files and checking them to see which operating system is opened.

Just execute **cat /etc/*release** and you'll see ... 
Kernel's info you could get from **uname** command. Best regards.

Comment: Thanks, I have to run a few tests over the weekend to find out if this is it.